# Different Result when calculating Polepairs with Octave vs Python

Tags: python-3.x, octave

I am trying to calculate pole pairs with both Octave 5.1.10 and Python 3.8.

The Octave code:

```matlab
wc=1
n=4
s={n}
G=1

function poles (n, wc, G)
    s={n}
    for k =1:n
    s{k}=wc*e^((j*(2*k+n-1)*pi)/(2*n))
    endfor
endfunction
```

The ouput is:

```matlab
s =
{
  [1,1] = -0.38268 + 0.92388i
  [1,2] = -0.92388 + 0.38268i
  [1,3] = -0.92388 - 0.38268i
  [1,4] = -0.38268 - 0.92388i
}
```

The Python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

wc=1  
n=4   
G=1   

def poles (n, wc, G):
    import math
    s=[] #contains the complex polpairs
    e=math.e
    pi=math.pi
    for k in range(n):
      s.append(wc*e**((1j*(2*k+n-1)*pi)/(2*n)))
    return s
```

returns

```py
s=[
(0.38268343236508984 + 0.9238795325112867j), 
(-0.3826834323650897 + 0.9238795325112867j), 
(-0.9238795325112867 + 0.3826834323650899j), 
(-0.9238795325112868 - 0.38268343236508967j)]
```

Can someone explain to me why these two outputs are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your octave loop, k takes values from 1 to 4.

In your python loop, k takes values from 0 to 3

If you want the same behaviour in your python loop, change

```
for k in range(4):
```

to

```
for k in range(1, 5):
```

Comment: @Adriaan alas, no, k is used directly in the computation. If you compare the two results you will confirm that the python result is basically one row off from the octave one.

Comment: Douh! Derpy me of course it has to be: for k in range(1, n+1). Thanks Mate!